# Why does my js script run multiple times when published to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, d3.js, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I have a site that is displaying an SVG image on the homepage, the image is drawn in js using d3.js .

When I preview the site the image appears fine and is interactive like i expect in multiple browsers.

However once it is published to azure and viewed on the same browsers the svg image is being repeated 2 more times so the image is present directly after each other 3 times on the home page.

In the html the drawing is created through a simple script call.

Can you display SVG images on a site that is being hosted inside azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone for your help, it was actually my naivete that was causing the problem, the way the script was being called was running the d3 draw code and then inside the script my colleague who wrote it was also calling the script after the function.

Just by removing all calls from the script and then calling the startDrawing() function in a script tag below the script tag where it is loaded means it is only drawn once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the mimetypes in order for Azure to tell clients what to do with the files when it gets them.

If you add this to your web.config, it should work...

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks but sadly it hasn't resolved the problem, it still shows 3 times

Comment: How the image 'shows' is not the right question to ask. Please work at the http level and figure out whether some requests are failing. Try to isolate it to a single request.

Comment: I have had a colleague who is quite good with debugging take a look but even he is stumped.
When the startDraw() is called at the bottom of the .js file, it seems to be called 2 extra times while it is published to Azure, however it is called only once when debugging from VS

Comment: Then it sounds like your question should be 'why does my js script run 3 times when called from Azure' which is closer to your actual problem

Comment: Thanks Michael I have updated the question to reflect the true problem.